# Getting Error In logcat while want to run my android application

Tags: java, android

Why This error?? Any Idea?

```
[2013-10-30 12:09:07 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.read(Client.java:698)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:311)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2013-10-30 12:09:07 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.read(Client.java:698)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:311)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2013-10-30 12:09:46 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2013-10-30 12:09:47 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:642)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:488)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:835)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:803)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:621)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

Comment: Yes, post your code. Also, do you not have any idea which line, or at list method or code block, throws this Exception? Debug it step-by-step to get an idea. It always helps to at least know where to look for errors.

Comment: Its run in bluestack bt not in emulator.. adb kill-server, adb start-server are solve this but again i am facing the same problem. Any permanent solution ??